# Dudas sobre vulnerabilidad en funcion Raw() laravel

Tags: php, laravel, seguridad

estaba leyendo en internet sobre inyecciones sql con el fin de hacer mi proyecto mas seguro, me encontre con muchos foros diciendo que cuando se usan las consultas `raw()` se crean vulnerabilidades para las inyecciones sql, por ejemplo tengo esta consulta en mi proyecto:

```
->when($isStartDate && $end_date, function ($query) use($start_date, $end_date){
            $query->whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE(orders.created_at)'),[$start_date,$end_date]);
        },function ($query) {
            return $query
                        ->whereYear('orders.created_at','=',date("Y"))
                        ->whereMonth('orders.created_at','=',date("m"));
        })
```

- La uso para filtrar el contenido de la consulta principal atraves de 2 fechas. Porque seria vulnerable?
- En muchos sitios mencionan "`DB::getPdo()->quote`" para contrarrestar esta vulnerabilidad, pero en ninguna sale algun ejemplo, como se usa esto?

Comment: Porque a travez de una inyeccion SQL se puede obtener datos de X a Y fecha, digamos que tu sistema es un sistema de gestion de ventas, no querras dejar una puerta abierta para que un atacante sepa que pasa por tu sistema de X a Y fecha. Lo que te recomiendo es que uses eloquent sobre queries raw, te ahorras los problemas de seguridad y el codigo es mas legible

Comment: @Ivandez y si se utiliza para hacer acciones especificas que no utilizen ningun parametro dado por el usuario? por ejemplo para sumar 2 datos de la bd?

Comment: Modelo::find(ID)->sum('precio'); me atreveria a decir que eloquent cubre casi cualquier necesidad que tengas.

Comment: No hay ninguna vulnerabilidad ahí. Las funciones RAW no son inseguras de por sí. La gente las vuelve inseguras cuando hace interpolación manual y tú no estás haciendo tal cosa

Comment: @ffflabs, podrias poner un ejemplo de interpolacion manual?, no he podido encontrar ejemplos, gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando interactúas con la BBDD sin un ORM de por medio, (digamos que usando el conector PDO) podrías verificar el login con algo como

```
 $login = $_POST['login'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $user =  $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE login='$login' AND password='$password'");
```

Por lo tanto si alguien manda el login `bobby'; DROP TABLE user; --` ejecutarás

```
 SELECT * FROM user WHERE login='bobby'; DROP TABLE user; -- etc etc
```

Eso es una inyección SQL y no se soluciona escapando las comillas, sino usando sentencias preparadas.

En Eloquent es difícil dispararse en el pie de esa manera, pero a menudo es necesario usar funciones RAW para casos de uso ligeramente más específicos que lo general. Eligiendo uno bien rebuscado, podrías querer comparar fonéticamente un término de búsqueda para cubrir errores de tipeo en tu buscador, usando la función [SOUNDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex). Obligado a usar RAW

```
    ->where(DB::raw('SOUNDEX(nombre)', '=', DB::raw("SOUNDEX('$term')"))
```

Con eso, un término de búsqueda como `bobby') OR 1=1;--` no te borrará la tabla pero podría enumerar todos los registros.

Inyectar SQL no es una ciencia exacta, pero si un sitio estuviera en modo debug y me mostrara los errores por pantalla, bastaría generar un error para ver la sentencia, y luego en pocos intentos aprovechar la sentencia para inyectar con éxito.

La versión en sentencia preparada de este ejemplo es:

```
 ->where(DB::raw('SOUNDEX(nombre)', '=', DB::raw("SOUNDEX(?)",[$term]))
```

y al quitar la interpolación manual, delegando en el conector el trabajo de entrecomillar el argumento, sea lo que sea que te manden no podrá cerrar maliciosamente el paréntesis para poner el `OR`.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de dar una respuesta tan detallada :), con el ejemplo me quedo clarisimo. Saludos desde chile

Comment: Chuta donde queda eso? Yo acá en Las Condes posom